# Differences between Izoard XP 2013 and Izoard XP 2014?

Tags: fork

I wanted to buy a Wilier Triestina Izoard XP.
The dealer told me that the Izoard XP 2013 with Shimano 105 cost 3021$ and I would have sold discounted to 2060$. The same price of the Izoard XP 2014 with 105. I asked why the new model would cost the same amount of discounted old model and he told me that the fork of the 2013 better than the 2014. I don't understand from [Izoard XP 2014 spec](http://www.airevalleycycles.com/m1b95s6p7713/WILIER-Izoard-XP-105-%282014%29) if it is better then Izoard XP 2013 see english 'Bike Specification' in this [italian site](http://www.wigglesport.it/wilier-izoard-xp-105-2013/). Is a matter of fork?

Comment: The 2014 link for the bike redirects to the homepage of wilier (which for en, gives the 2012 bike).

Comment: @Batman thanks a lot! I've tried to use a bitly url now I don't know if it works...

Comment: Is http://www.airevalleycycles.com/m1b95s6p7713/WILIER-Izoard-XP-105-(2014) the same thing? I haven't been able to load the bitly url either. If so, 2014 gives you a tiagra FD (vs 105), 12-28 cassette (vs 12-25), Tektro brakes (vs FSA) and a slightly lighter wheelset (~50g). There aren't really details on the fork, and tiagra is still pretty good (though a larger cassette range is useful for some people). Take them both out and buy the one that you like better - It doesn't seem to be particularly jarring in changes).

Comment: @GM URL shorteners are typically frowned up on on Stack Exchange sites. We greatly prefer the long, ugly URL. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113658/no-url-shorteners

Comment: @jimirings I've already delated the Bitly url I've used it for a problem in visiting the italian site, however maybe this is not the right site to ask question about bicycles so I think I will soon delate the question.

Comment: @GM I saw that. I was just letting you know for future reference. I personally don't think your question is a bad one. I was actually surprised that it received a downvote.

Comment: @jimirings thanks for your advice and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annual improvements in bikes tend to small and incremental. They have been doing this for over 100 years, unless someone comes out with something revolutionary, its hard to see how they can make a big difference. If it is revolutionary, it won't be the same model name (and it wont be 105).

For me, a grand in the wallet makes the 2013 a better bike. In a year, the 2014 will be a grand cheaper and in two years the same price on the second hand market as the 2013. If I wanted to spend $3000, I would buy the 2013 model of a $4500 bike.

Only you can decide if small incremental improvements are worth the money to you.

Comment: Generally changes are incremental, but sometimes they are drastic (at some point, a lot of bike lines such as the Specialized Hardrock moved from steel to aluminium for example). These days, a lot of changes do tend to be small or cost saving (like replacing the fork with a slightly lower end fork), so the older model may indeed be better. Also note that one bike model can come in several trim levels depending on where you buy it, so you really need to make sure you're comparing the exact trim levels you're considering purchasing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the 2013' it's awesome.
The 2014 looks cheaper because of cheaper parts (1/2 tiagra) and wheels. Get the 2013. Anything less than 105 groupset doesn't do the frame justice.  Get the 2013 Upgrade the tyres day 1 and the wheels down the track.